# DIO Control Code Needed

Tags: c#, winforms, io, device

Does any one have the constant value of [IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363411%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for use with the dll import in a C# class?
I was told the constants are in WinIoCtl.h, but they are nowhere to be found.

If someone could provide it, it would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WinIoCtl.h that comes with Windows SDK v5.0:

```
#define CTL_CODE( DeviceType, Function, Method, Access ) (                 \
    ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method) \
)

#define METHOD_BUFFERED                 0

#define FILE_ANY_ACCESS                 0

#define FILE_DEVICE_MASS_STORAGE        0x0000002d

#define IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE FILE_DEVICE_MASS_STORAGE

#define IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER CTL_CODE(IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE, 0x0304, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

So it's 2952208 or 0x2d0c10.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get it to work. I think it is a problem with my code: http://pastie.org/1321798 I use disk geom because that is the only way I can usually get it to return a value. It will often be a random field in the struct.

Comment: @Eaton: That's a different question :-) I can only help with the value of the control code.

Comment: Ha, ok. I got it to work, but it appears the operation isn't supported based on the Win32 exception.. Hmm..